# MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate Permission Check Swift

Tags: ios, swift, permissions

I have the following code in my project to select audio files through 'MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate'. When run the below code, for the first time the user is prompted to grant permission. If the user declines the loading the picker would silently fail.

Is there a way to prompt user to grant permission if they return after declining at first?

I was wondering if it's a bug. Is there any way we can detect the permission of the MPMediaPickerControllerDelegate so that we can decide to show the audio or not.

Below is my code:

```
let myMediaPickerVC = MPMediaPickerController(mediaTypes: MPMediaType.anyAudio)
myMediaPickerVC.allowsPickingMultipleItems = false
myMediaPickerVC.delegate = self
present(myMediaPickerVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to first check the authorization permission, then run your code if authorizationStatus permission is `authorized`. If it is not `notDetermined` then ask for permission. If it `denied` then show Alert asking user to go to Settings and enable this permission.

```
MPMediaLibrary.requestAuthorization({(newPermissionStatus: MPMediaLibraryAuthorizationStatus) in  
    // This code will be called after the user allows or denies your app permission.  
    switch (permissionStatus) {  
        case MPMediaLibraryAuthorizationStatus.authorized:  
             print("permission status is authorized")  
        case MPMediaLibraryAuthorizationStatus.notDetermined:  
             print("permission status is not determined")  
          MPMediaLibrary.requestAuthorization(MPMediaLibraryAuthorizationStatus -> permissionStatus)  
        case MPMediaLibraryAuthorizationStatus.denied:  
             print("permission status is denied")  
        case MPMediaLibraryAuthorizationStatus.restricted:  
             print("permission status is restricted")  
    }  
})
```

Comment: Thank you sir, i am trying your code but return no status, when this code written on viewDidLoad they check first line and skip the all code. i'm really confused why?

Comment: Use this code after - `viewDidAppear`.. Or you can use delay by DispatchQueue.asyncAfter(.now()+0.5){... this code here}

Comment: @ShamDass As in `viewDidLoad` it cant navigate or show other vcs, so either use delay or use this code after `viewDidAppear`

Comment: If this is working... then accept this answer and upvote